# Two select field cck field

Tags: entities

I need to implement two select field in a content type.Currently cck modules allows only one select field. So how can I implement two select fields using cck.

Eg:- select field value for months and year.

Tks in adv
Vil

Comment: do you want to create select field for month and year only ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module. This provides the cck widget to select the date.

The Select List date widget presents users with a drop-down list or textfield for each part of the date (year, month, day, hour, etc.). The whole selector is collapsed onto a single line using css (except for the timezone selector, if date-specific timezones are collected). The selector is highly configurable and you can set it up to use 5, 10, or 15 minute increments for minutes and seconds, or make some parts of the selector use textfields instead of drop-downs, useful to allow any year without creating a huge drop-down selector.

For more Documentation [See here](http://drupal.org/node/1326872)

Comment: yea but i have to keep options like Select option 1:-0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 | Select option 2:- 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 so on..

Comment: and are they dependent ? I mean value of 2nd select is dependent to first one ?

Comment: No they just work individually...anyways came up with a solution. Tks for your replies :)